# JNI calling JVM functions/events from native code?

Tags: java, c++, applet, jvm, java-native-interface

I am wondering if it is possible for native functions to signal Java functions/events?

Basically I think I will run some C++ code on a separate thread and do stuff like handling SIP and then for example if the native thread detects an incomming call, being able to signal the JVM somehow. I am not sure how communication like this is done in JNI.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several good articles around, like [this one](http://java.sys-con.com/node/45840).  Here's a [Developer Works](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/tutorials/j-jni/) article that looks good too.